# rpm build for different os.version

Tags: redhat, rpm

I would like for a RHEL6 build machine to construct a RHEL5 compatible rpm using the maven rpm build plugin.   I see how to modify the arch (amd64 vs i386) and os.name (linux vs. ...) but not  RHEL5 vs. RHEL5.

Comment: What do you believe you need to change to make your RPM RHEL5 compatible here?

Comment: The catalyst is the following error that occurs when I construct the rpm with RHEL6 but not with RHEL5.   

    rpm -i /tmp/fts-app-0.0.0051-233583.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by fts-app-0.0.0051-233583.noarch
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by fts-app-0.0.0051-233583.noarch

Comment: I'm not sure, offhand, what `rpmlib(FileDigests)` is but the other is that RHEL6 introduced a new compression format available for rpms. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9292243/258523) for how to control the payload compression type.

Comment: A quick look at the output from `rpm --showrc` makes it looks like you might be able to replace the value of `_dbi_tags` to get rid of the `Filedigests` stuff. I have `_dbi_tags  Packages:Name:Basenames:Group:Requirename:Providename:Conflictname:Triggername:Dirnames:Requireversion:Provideversion:Installtid:Sigmd5:Sha1header:Filemd5s:Depends:Pubkeys` on CentOS 5 and `_dbi_tags  Packages:Name:Basenames:Group:Requirename:Providename:Conflictname:Obsoletename:Triggername:Dirnames:Requireversion:Provideversion:Installtid:Sigmd5:Sha1header:Filedigests:Depends:Pubkeys` on CentOS 6.

Comment: Um no. All rpmlib(...) tracking dependencies are added to deliberately poison packaging when a new and/or incompatible feature is added to rpm. The poisoning deliberately prevents attempting (in this case) creating XZ-compressed, SHA256 digested, packages built on RHEL6 but installed on RHEL5.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a chroot (or perhaps run a VM or docker image, or use mock) that contains RHEL5 on the RHEL6 host, and use that for building packages.

There are specific ways to configure rpm to use ZLIB rather than XZ, and use MD5 rather than SHA256, as well as to change labeling of RHEL6 vs RHEL5.

There is no one magic switch to achieve building RHEL5 on RHEL6 (without using mock etc isolation) because RHEL5 and RHEL6 are distinct operating systems with different API's and versions which will block success for all but trivial packages.