# How to reduce the size of an rpm?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am creating an rpm which will scatter some files in different/specific locations on its installation. The problem I am facing is the size of the rpm, which is close to 1.5 GB. Is there a way in which I could place my files in aws s3 and get download during the rpm installation. As of now I included all my files inside the SOURCE directory.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Balasekhar Nelli

Comment: You might have better luck on serverfault.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can generate yum/dnf repository with deltas:

```
createrepo_c --deltas
```

It will create binary diff against old rpm file. It will not help you with initial download, but it will speed up upgrades.

Do not forget to have in `yum.conf`

```
deltarpm=2
```

See man yum.conf for what this value means.

You can also change compression parameters when building rpm. See this answer:
[rpmbuild change compression format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292243/rpmbuild-change-compression-format)

Answer (score 0):

For that amount of data, do **not** put it in an rpm, not even 100 of them (e.g. mypgm-data-1.rpm, mypgm-data-2.rpm, ...).  Personally, I *hate* it when I see some programs updating foobar-langpack-1.rpm to foobar-langpack-300.rpm when I'm running yum.

Consider using rsync [tunneled through http?] instead to AWS.  It's perfect for the job.

Why are you "scattering them around"???  Why aren't you putting them under /home/mypgm or /usr/share/mypgm?

The rpm install should be quick.  You *can* have the rpm post do the rsync, but I wouldn't do it until the user runs the program and/or config for the first time.  It would ask:  "Enable automatic/background data updates?"

Give the user a choice.  When the program runs it can detect that the local data needs to be refreshed from AWS and [again] prompt the user:  "I need to update the program data before I can run.  Do it now?  It will take X minutes"

For something this massive, give the user a choice about update *policy*.  For example, on Android, you can select "update over wifi only".