# rpm size differs, extracted content same

Tags: linux, cmake, rpm, rpmbuild

I have two rpms, (generated after changing couple of lines of code). one rpm is of 25mb other rpm is  of 40+ mb. If I extract both rpms, they both are of same size 129mb(in fact the first rpm size is bigger by few bytes). I don't think metadata will differ so much. What could be the problem here ?

Comment: maybe you could say what lines of code you changed? Did you change anything in the spec file? or in your build command?

Comment: Hi Thanks for response. I found the solution. The problem was with rpm compression macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of compression of RPM payload. See:

- [rpmbuild change compression format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292243/rpmbuild-change-compression-format)
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/XZRpmPayloads